# CSS: Background Image over Background Gradient

Tags: css

Having problems where I have a background gradient and a background image (transparent PNG) for my div, but no matter what, only the color gradient will display and not the image. If I do it as a solid color, I can get the image to display. Here's my current CSS;

```
div {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(224, 34, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(88, 0, 55, 1) 100%), url('path/to/image/png') no-repeat;
}
```

Any way to make this work without the addition of another div?

Comment: Use `background-blend-mode: overlay` and toy with the color opacity value. Order of image vs gradient does matter.

Comment: That worked! Didn't even have to play with the opacity. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> These are layered atop one another with the first background you provide on top and the last background listed in the back. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds)

```css
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/lizard.png') no-repeat, linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(224, 34, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(88, 0, 55, 1) 100%);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**solution** as commented:

- Given the OP example CSS simply add `background-blend-mode: overlay` and optionally fiddle with the `rgb()` color *opacity* value to fine-tune the end result. Depending on the required end result, you may need to swap the image and gradient in the `background` definition as the order *does* matter.

**extra**

To test the solution myself, I created a fun demo to demonstrate the difference between the original order versus the image and gradient getting swapped.

As you can see in the demo, I used `background-image` instead of the shorthand `background` property. This will help code optimization when you want to reuse or vary on the background definition.

Lastly, as background color I used the complementary color of the gradients purple to demonstrate a `background-blend-mode` with a delimited list of different *blend modes* (see `.grad4` and `.grad5`).

**bonus**

Make sure to enable `[class*="grad"] { background-attachment }` and see what happens when the browser window gets resized...

**snippet**

```css
.wrapper {
    /* Create a few custom properties for easy manipulation */
    --opacity : 1;
    --image   : url('https://picsum.photos/id/26/1000');
    --gradient: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(224,34,153, var(--opacity)) 0%,
                                        rgb( 88, 0, 55, var(--opacity)) 100%);
}

/* Define background variations for demo use */
.grad0         { background-image: var(--image) }
.grad1         { background-image: var(--gradient) }
.grad2, .grad4 { background-image: var(--image), var(--gradient) }
.grad3, .grad5 { background-image: var(--gradient), var(--image) }

/* Solution as commented on SO (using above custom vars, though) */
.solution {
    background: var(--gradient), var(--image) no-repeat;
    background-blend-mode: overlay; /* mix/match the image and gradient */
    background-size: cover;         /* [OPTIONAL], just to make the image fit */
}

[class*="grad"] { /* all elements with class containing 'grad' */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-blend-mode: overlay;

    /* toy with these */
    background-size      : cover; /* scale to fit */
/*    background-attachment: fixed; /* for a shared bg */

}
.grad4, .grad5 {
     /* try swapping blend modes */
    background-blend-mode: overlay, difference;
    background-color: rgb(34,224,105, var(--opacity));
    /* A bright green, the complementary color of the purple color */
}

/***************************/
/* just demo page settings */
/***************************/
*    { box-sizing: border-box }
body { margin: 0 }

.wrapper {
    display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 0.5rem; padding: 0.5rem;
}

.test {
    display: grid; place-items: center;
    width: 200px; aspect-ratio: 1;

    font-size: calc(1.25vmin + 0.5rem);
    /* y=mx+b => y=0.0125x + 8 with (320,12)(1280,24) */

    color: White; border: 1px solid Black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="test grad0"   >image only    </div>
    <div class="test grad1"   >gradient only </div>
    <div class="test solution">solution      </div>
    <div class="test grad2"   >image first   </div>
    <div class="test grad3"   >gradient first</div>
    <div class="test grad4"   >image first   </div>
    <div class="test grad5"   >gradient first</div>
</div>
```